# vba script hangs at Workbook.Close

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a hello world application in Visual Basic for Applications, namely, to modify a cell in an Excel sheet. Here it is:

```
Sub hello()

    Dim obj As Object
    Dim Workbook As Object

    Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set Workbook = obj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\gbuday\Desktop\Oktatás\Excel\start.xlsx")

    Workbook.Worksheets("Munka1").Range("B3") = "Hello World!"

    Workbook.Close
    Set Workbook = Nothing
    Set obj = Nothing

End Sub
```

When running, Excel hangs and I cannot stop the script running, only kill the excel process.  Debugging it, it hangs at the `Workbook.Close` line. What is the problem with that line?

Comment: See http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/vba/xl_doesnt_quit/ Normally when automating you would use `WB.Quit` before a `Set WB = Nothing`. Also good practice not to use an Object (Workbook) as a varianle name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not giving Excel enough time to finish it's operations. Usually a `DoEvents` will solve the problem. Also to avoid confusion, you might want to name your variable as `wbk' instead of 'Workbook'

```
Sub hello()
    Dim obj As Object, wbk As Object

    Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wbk = obj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\gbuday\Desktop\Oktatás\Excel\start.xlsx")

    wbk.Worksheets("Munka1").Range("B3") = "Hello World!"

    DoEvents

    '~~> Change True to False if you do not want to save
    wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Set wbk = Nothing: Set obj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Siddharth, it worked. The crucial thing was the SaveChanges clause.

Comment: +1 (although making a change ten not saving it looks strange)

Comment: @brettdj: Very True :). However in many scenarios (May not be the above), we open a workbook to get some calculations done, use the output for some other calculations and then close the workbook without saving so I thought, I might just explain in a one liner as a comment and leave it up to the asker on what exactly he/she wants...

Comment: I think the issue is that there was a dialogue box asking to save and it appeared to the user as if it was hanging. Was not aware DoEvents is available in C#?

Comment: Came from a C# question my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
Workbooks.Close
```

I also think that "Workbook" is a reserved word and you should use something like "wb" instead.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
```