# Macro freezes word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a very basic macro as shown below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceNumReviewers()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
   Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

   Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\crouz\Desktop\data.xlsx")



   ThisDocument.numManager.Caption = exWb.Sheets("FeedbackData").Cells(7, 2)
   ThisDocument.numPeers.Caption = exWb.Sheets("FeedbackData").Cells(8, 2)
   ThisDocument.numDirectReports.Caption = exWb.Sheets("FeedbackData").Cells(9, 2)
   ThisDocument.numTotal.Caption = exWb.Sheets("FeedbackData").Cells(10, 2)

   exWb.Close
   Set exWb = Nothing

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When I run it via a button added to the Quick Access Toolbar, it runs, replaces the values then freezes the word document. I can use other applications without problems except MS Word which I have to kill via the Process Manager.

I am very new to VBA and macros and was wondering what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in the debugger to see if there's a specific line that's causing an error? Would recommend commenting out `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` until you get the issue resolved - just makes your life easier. Also, you indicate that this is freezing _Word_, but I don't see any references to MS Word, only Excel. Maybe post some additional code? Where does `ThisDocument` come from?

Comment: @FreeMan `ThisDocument` is the Word document where the macro is...

Comment: The [Tag:Excel-VBA] tag confused me, so I've edited to retag [tag:Word-VBA]. Also, I'd still recommend stepping through in the debugger to see exactly which line causes it to hang. If you identify that, someone may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: exWb.Close is the line which hangs everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to solve the problem.

I had to replace

```
exWb.Close
```

with

```
exWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Now it does not hang anymore.
Thank you all for the help and putting me in the right direction with the debugger.

I found the answer here: [vba script hangs at Workbook.Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797367/vba-script-hangs-at-workbook-close)

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your macro, you have

```
application.screenupdating=false
```

Is that a typo? If not, change it to True to unfreeze Word.

Comment: Yes it is a typo, I have got it set to true, so it is no that I'm afraid. When I run the macro from the VBE, I keep getting the busy blue circle.

Comment: I'm not familiar with transitioning between excel and word in VBA, but it may be hung up with trying to get the cell object into a caption. Does .cells().value produce the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Handle errors.

```
Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'your code here

CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'rest of cleanup code here
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    'handle errors here
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

That way you're sure that `ScreenUpdating` is always set back to `True` whether or not a runtime error occurs (which is probably the case here).

Comment: Sorry @Mat but it still freezes even with your code added.

Comment: and no error? if you put a breakpoint on the `Resume CleanExit` line, is the breakpoint hit?

Comment: No, the breakpoint doesn't get hit, at least as far as I can tell, nothing happens and WINWORD.exe freezes all my word documents that are open

Comment: [@Freeman's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350122/macro-freezes-word#comment46886637_29350122) looks like a good lead.