# Excel Crashes on wb.Close in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Everything in this code works fine, except at the very end when I go to close the workbook that I am performing some operations on. I'm inserting some code into ThisWorkbook of the workbook that I'm opening from a text file and also copying a few tabs in my master spreadsheet to each workbook that I open in this loop.  At the end of the loop it crashes when I try to close and move on to the next workbook.

```
Sub AddSht_AddCode()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim xCom As Variant
Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim xLine As Long
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim strFolderPathTo As String
Dim strCodePath As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim mergearea As Range
Dim c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
strFolderPath = Sheets("Master - DO NOT MOVE").Range("B2").Value

strCodePath = Sheets("Master - DO NOT MOVE").Range("b18").Value
If IsNull(strFolderPath) Or strFolderPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please make sure you have a valid DFF path entered in Cell B2 on the Master worksheet.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Dir(strFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "The DFF folder path entered is not a valid path.  Please edit and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
End If

'create_projid_array
'create_projid_new

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

'If (InStr(objFile.Name, ".xlsm") > 0 Or InStr(objFile.Name, ".xlsx") > 0) And check_var_array(Left(objFile.Name, InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".") - 1), projarray) = 1 Then
'If (InStr(objFile.Name, ".xlsx") > 0 Or InStr(objFile.Name, ".xlsb") > 0) And check_var_array(Left(objFile.Name, InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".") - 1), projarray) = 1 Then
If (InStr(objFile.Name, ".xlsm") > 0) Then
'If check_var_array(objFile.Name, projarray) = 1 Then

    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(objFile, False)
    'Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI

    Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Activate
    If Right(objFile.Name, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
        Sheets(Array("Template", "Log")).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
        If Sheets("Master - DO NOT MOVE").Range("B4") = True Then
        wb.Activate
        wb.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Clear
        wb.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").Value = 0
        Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Sheets("Data").Range("B1:BO2400").Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("Data").Range("B1")
        End If
    End If

    wb.Activate
    wb.Sheets(1).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    wb.Sheets(1).Unprotect Password:="xxxxxxxxx"
    Set mergearea = wb.Sheets(1).Range("i5:l6")
    For Each c In mergearea
    If c.MergeCells Then
    c.UnMerge
    End If
    Next
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("J5").ClearContents
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("j6").ClearContents
    'Selection.UnMerge
    'Selection.ClearContents

    If Right(objFile.Name, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
        wb.Sheets("Template").Visible = xlSheetVisible
        wb.Sheets("Data").Visible = xlSheetVisible

        Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Activate
            If Sheets("Master - DO NOT MOVE").Range("B4") = True Then
            wb.Activate
            wb.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Clear
            wb.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").Value = 0
            Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Sheets("Data").Range("B1:BO2400").Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("Data").Range("B1")
            End If

        Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Activate

        If Sheets("Master - DO NOT MOVE").Range("B6") = True Then
        wb.Activate
        wb.Sheets("Template").UsedRange.Clear
        Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Sheets("Template").Range("A1:G524").Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("Template").Range("A1")
            If Left(wb.Sheets(1).Range("I7"), 3) = "PO " Or Left(wb.Sheets(1).Range("I7"), 3) = "PO#" Then
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("I7").Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("Template").Range("F3")
            End If
        End If
    End If

    wb.Activate
    Call update_dropdowns
    Call update_ga_formula(wb.Name)

    wb.Sheets(Array("Template", "Data")).Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    wb.Activate
With wb
    Set xPro = .VBProject
    Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule
    xMod.DeleteLines 1, _
    xMod.CountOfLines
    xMod.AddFromFile strCodePath
End With

    wb.Activate
With wb.Sheets(1)
.Protect Password:="xxxxxxx", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
.EnableOutlining = True
End With

    wb.Save
    wb.Close  <<<<<EXCEL CRASHES HERE>>>>>>>

End If

Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vba script hangs at Workbook.Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797367/vba-script-hangs-at-workbook-close)

Comment: I tried that already.  Still getting the same issue

Comment: A few suggestions: 1) Try moving the wb.Save before wb.Sheets(1).Protect 2) Check if wb is protected (not only the sheets) 3) if any, check the code in the wb close / save events (BeforeClose, BeforeSave, SheetDeactivate, WindowDeactivate, etc) for any invalid actions. Not related, but remove the `.Activate` statements and qualify the objects if needed

Comment: I tried moving the save and that didn't work.  There is only 1 worksheet that is protected in the target workbook..not the whole workbook.  When Excel crashes it references an error number 1033?? not sure if that means anything.  What do you mean by "qualifying the objects"?  Also, I should say when you close any of the workbooks that this is operating on manually it is fine.

Comment: So your comment triggered a thought though as I think the BeforeClose event that I'm putting in the target workbook is the culprit.  So I changed the wb.Close to Application.EnableEvents = False .... wb.Close .... Application.EnableEvents = True .... and now it works fine!  Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: tried a doevents between save and close?

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it. By removing the `.Activate` statements and qualifying objects I mean that these 2 lines `Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Activate: If Sheets("Master - DO NOT MOVE").Range("B4") = True Then` should be replaced by `If Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Sheets("Master - DO NOT MOVE").Range("B4") = True Then` (`.Select` and `.Activate` statements are not needed and have poor performance). Edit: the comment is hard to read - I'll include this in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to finalize:

In my specific situation I was adding a BeforeClose Event to the target workbook ThisWorkbook object.  In the code that is performing this operation, it was crashing after the BeforeClose code was inserted in the target workbook and upon having the source code try to close the workbook with wb.Close.

I changed:

```
wb.Close
```

to

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
wb.Close
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

So, bypassed the target workbook events altogether and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code in the wb close / save events for any invalid actions:

- BeforeClose()
- BeforeSave()
- SheetDeactivate()
- WindowDeactivate(), etc

---

Not related, but remove the `.Activate` statements and qualify the objects if needed

For example:

```
Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Activate
    If Sheets("Master - DO NOT MOVE").Range("B4") = True Then
```

should be replaced with

```
If Workbooks("DFFPHI_w_QAQC.xlsm").Sheets("Master - DO NOT MOVE").Range("B4") = True Then
```

---

Statements `.Select` and `.Activate` are not needed and have poor performance